# How to add operator extension as a part of context of the specific class without subclassing?

Tags: operator-overloading, kotlin

I'm trying to utilize operators for Wicket, which is painfully verbose.

My most wanted feature is to use an unary "+" to `add()` a component.
But it will be needed to work inside context of every `MarkupContainer` descendants.

Use should be like this:

```
class SomePage() : WebPage() {
    init {
        // SomePage{} context
        +Label("someLabel","Some label") 
        // instead of this.add(Label("someLabel","Some label"))
        +object : StatelessForm<Unit>("someForm") {
            init {
                // StatelessForm{} context
                +Label("fieldLabel","Field label") 
                +RequiredTextField("someField")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to implement this now without subclassing everything? Some *imaginary* syntax of what i want:

```
extend org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer {
    operator fun<T: Component> T.unaryPlus():T {
        // add() is called as a method of a MarkupContainer instance
        add(this) // this@MarkupContainer.add(this@unaryPlus)
        return this
    }
}
```

- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html
- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`unaryPlus`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#unary-operations) operator (`+Component`) is harder in this context since, as the *unary* implies, it's a single operand operator (single input). There's a sort of hacky solution though:

```
class ExtOf<out T : MarkupContainer>(val self: T) {
    companion object {
        private val lastConfiguredContainer = ThreadLocal<ExtOf<MarkupContainer>?>()

        fun <T : MarkupContainer> configure(container: T, configurer: ExtOf<T>.() -> Any?): T {
            val currentLast = lastConfiguredContainer.get()
            try {
                val newCurrent = ExtOf(container)
                lastConfiguredContainer.set(newCurrent)
                newCurrent.configurer()
            } finally {
                lastConfiguredContainer.set(currentLast)
            }
            return container
        }
    }

    operator fun <T2 : Component> T2.unaryPlus(): T2 {
        val container = lastConfiguredContainer.get()
        container!!.self.add(this) //TODO throw a nice exception explaining how ot use the `configure`
        return this
    }
}

fun <T : MarkupContainer> T.configure(configurer: ExtOf<T>.() -> Any?) = ExtOf.configure(this, configurer)
```

The above maintains information about last configured [`MarkupContainer`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/MarkupContainer.html) in a [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) private variable that is used to supply the receiver of [`add`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/MarkupContainer.html#add(org.apache.wicket.Component...)) method.

You can then write:

```
class SomePage() : WebPage() {
    init {
        configure {
            +Label("someLabel", "Some label")

            +StatelessForm<Unit>("someForm").configure {
                // StatelessForm{} context
                +Label("fieldLabel", "Field label")
                +RequiredTextField<Long>("someField")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I mentioned above the solution while works is far from being pretty. It can be confusing (as often overloaded operators are) so I'd advice using the regular `add` like so:

```
class SomePage() : WebPage() {
    init {
        add(
            Label("someLabel", "Some label"),

            StatelessForm<Unit>("someForm").apply {
                // StatelessForm{} context
                add(
                  Label("fieldLabel", "Field label"),
                  RequiredTextField<Long>("someField")
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*I guess ideally there would be a library similar to [anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) but for wicket.*

Comment: That's a clever trick but personally I wouldn't recommend doing that. It's not easy to grasp what's going on. I would just use `add` (with multiple arguments) instead of the first `configure` and `apply` with `add` for the second. It's not really longer and plain simple.

Comment: @ChristophLeiter Fully agree, still it was a nice exercise :)

Answer (score -1):

I believe it's not possible

The problem is that unaryPlus operator fun cannot have any params. You want to use unaryPlus inside MarkupContainer class, but you also want to add component (other class, other reference with technicly could be a param)

The only way I see it could work would be with subclassing (Component subclass MarkupContainer) and unaryPlus perator extension to MarkupContainer

```
class Label(name: String, b: String) : Component() {}
open class MarkupContainer() {
fun add(component: Component) {
    println("added" + this)
}
}
open class Component() : MarkupContainer() {}
open class StatelessForm<T>(name: String) : Component()
operator fun Component.unaryPlus() {
add(this)
}

class SomePage() : Component() {
init {
    add(Label("someLabel", "Some label"))
    +Label("someLabel", "Some label")

    +object : StatelessForm<Unit>("someForm") {
        init {
            // StatelessForm{} context
            +Label("fieldLabel", "Field label")
        }
    }
}
}
```